# Show Jdewit Bootstrap Timepicker as inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker, bootstrap-timepicker

Trying out the Jdewit Bootstrap Timepicker (http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/), is there any way to use it inline instead of in a dropdown or modal? From what I've been testing I haven't been able to produce an inline version, is this possible?

All help greatly appreciated.